# How do i add a line break in render()?

Tags: reactjs

in my `render()` function i have the following code:

```
    render:function(){
       var cbCollection = this.state.cbData.map(function(elem, index) {

            return <label><input type = "checkbox"  name = "cbCodes"  id = "cb-{index}" value={elem.Id}/>{elem.DiagCodes}</label><br />

        })

return(<div>rest of the code</div>)

    }
```

but it wont let me add the `<br />` at the end as coded, why is this and how do i fix this?

Comment: Wrap it all in a span

Comment: or wrap in a div, react element need to have one parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the OP does not post an answer, I'd like to steal the points :D

```
render: function(){
  var cbCollection = this.state.cbData.map(function(elem, index) {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="cbCodes" id="cb-{index}" value{elem.Id} />
          {elem.DiagCodes}
        </label>
        <br />
      </div>
    ); 
  })
}
```